# Tags on teams have extremely poor contrast on dark mode

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Something that came up in a discussion on other things was that tags were pretty hard to read on dark mod on teams

[image]

Contrast the add people button (which looks *vaguely* taggy but isn't - which might be an issue on its own, with the discussion button (which actually is a tag) and with a SO dark mode tag as below

[image]

Its extremely non contrasty and hard to read - and I suspect my screenshots will render bigger than actual size for most.

Could we have easier to read/more distinct tags on dark mode for SO teams?